# Virtualhosts Configuration in Apache/Resin (running Adobe Coldfusion8)

Tags: apache, coldfusion, resin, caucho

I have *development* server setup running Adobe Coldfusion8 (.war install) on top of Caucho Resin v3.1.9.  (CentOS 5.3-64bit)

**note**: This is my first experience with Resin.  I am trying to run Coldfusion8 on top of Resin as I was suggested that this would give me great performance gains.

**My question is**: how I can easily integrate multiple apache virtualhosts like my existing configuration.

On my production server, running CF8, standalone install on Adobe supplied JRun via mod_jrun22.so in apache, I have virtual hosts setup for each of my websites pointing to '/var/www/*/html/, similar to the following (simplified):

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/www.mydomain.com/html
ServerName www.mydomain.com
ServerAlias mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/www.myotherdomain.com/html
ServerName www.myotherdomain.com
ServerAlias myotherdomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

This configuration allows me to setup virtual hosts through apache pointing to '/var/www/*/html' so I can quickly deploy websites with Coldfusion Apps.

Well with Resin, it appears I have to also setup <host> tags for each one of my virtual hosts in '/opt/resin/conf/resin.conf'. Thus, having to completely duplicate apache virtual hosts.

What I really want is to be able to setup my apache virtual hosts and then have resin compensate accordingly.

I need a better solution and am completely open to entertaining any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [resin docs](http://www.caucho.com/resin/doc/host-tags.xtp#host) it shows an example using regex to change the root directory. Could you create a similar regex that just caught any .com site and set the document root?

From playing with resin/railo and caucho I couldn't find a way at all to just have the virtualhost configuration in apache only. You have to duplicate it to some level anyway. Either by a regex  entry or as I did (only had about 10 domains) create a  entry for each site.

Comment: I didn't really like this answer. :-)  I have hundreds of websites, even using ServerAlias, so to setup a Regex site isn't going to work well.  Having to duplicate my apache hosts in resin seems ridiculous to me and overkill.  Now I have to manage apache & resin?  This is a setback for me.